# Disable specific log outputs with slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I would like to disable a specific log output (in this case the InterruptedException logging) when running my tests but I do not want to disable it in production.
The reason for this is that it generates a lot of noise even for passing tests when the test is teared down.

In the code below i disable the `log.warn("Handling InterruptedException", failure)` when I run my tests.   Currently I pass a flag `isLogInterruptedExceptionsEnabled` to this class which is checked in the code but this is quite ugly for a couple of reasons.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    log.debug("Enter run method");

    try {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                // some code
            } catch (Throwable failure) {
                if (!isCausedByInterruptedException(failure)) {
                    log.error("Handling failure", failure);
                } else if (isLogInterruptedExceptionsEnabled) {
                    log.warn("Handling InterruptedException", failure);
                }

                // some code
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        log.warn("Exception handling was interrupted. Exiting Supervisor.", ex);

        // some code
    }

    log.debug("Exit run method because interrupted");
}
```

Is there a better way to disable some specific logging output?
Maybe there is also the possibility to not log the complete strack trace, that would also be a good option. 
I was also thinking of setting the log level to ERROR this would be also an option here but maybe not in other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Add a logging properties file (e.g. log4j.properties if using Log4J) to your test dependencies (e.g. ./src/test/resources if using Maven) which sets the logging level to a reduced level (off even). This is ideal if you don't need the verbose logging for tests as you rely on asserts and easy enough to switch back on for debugging tests.